# How to clone and place two different items in jquery in the respective positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div and a button to close that div. I am cloning them both separately and assigning a unique incrementing id to both. Everything is working in that the cloning happens and the button closes the Div.
I have a problem though regarding the placement of the button. I want the button to always be in the same position with reference to its cloned div. Any ideas how to do this?

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="hideDiv(this)" id="btn">X</a>
<div id="id"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="duplicateDiv()">Add</a>
```

Javascript

```
function duplicateDiv(){ 
    $('#btn').clone().attr('id', 'btn'+ cloneCount2++).insertBefore($('[id^=id]:first'));

    $('#id').clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++).insertAfter($('[id^=id]:first'));

    //clearing the input items in the new cloned div
    $("#id").find("input").val("");     
}


function hideDiv(obj){
    var currentId = $(obj).attr('id');
    var divId = currentId.replace("btn", "id");
    $("#"+divId).hide();
    $("#"+currentId).hide();
}
```

Comment: Show some HTML if you want help with HTML (and you do)

Comment: do a jsfiddle and post it,  we'll be able to assist you from there as we'll be able to see both what your trying to do and then show you a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interpret Question correctly , try using `.appendTo()` , `.insertAfter($("#btn" + cloneCount))`

```js
var cloneCount = 0, cloneCount2 = 0;

function duplicateDiv() {

  //the close button
  $("#btn")
  .clone().attr("id", function(_, id) {
        return id + (++cloneCount2)
  })
  .appendTo("body")
  
  $("#id")
  .clone().attr("id", function(_, id) {
        return id + (++cloneCount)
  })
  .insertAfter($("#btn" + cloneCount))

  //clearing the input items in the new cloned div
  $("#id").find("input").val("");
}

function hideDiv(obj) {

  var currentId = $(obj).attr('id');
  var divId = currentId.replace("btn", "id");
  $("#" + divId).hide();
  $("#" + currentId).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="hideDiv(this)" id="btn">X</a>
<div id="id">div</div>
<a href="#" onclick="duplicateDiv()">Add</a>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm doing exactly as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

### One of the way is Jquery Offset

```
var destination = $('.original-content').offset(); // get position of original
$('.original-content').hide(); // hide original
$('.cloned-content').css({top: destination.top, left: destination.left}); // set position of cloned
```